# Powershell Convert String to Byte Size

Tags: string, powershell, type-conversion, data-conversion

How can I change an integer or string variable into a byte size as below?

```
$examineLine = 35
$copySizeLimit = $examineLine+MB
$copySizeLimit
```

For the above example, turning the number 35 into 35MB output should be 36700160
But error:

"You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator."

Comment: It should be `$copySizeLimit = $examineLine/MB` not + which would give you the MB representation of 35 bytes

Comment: I changed it but now get: "You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator."

Comment: Figured it out. I needed $examineLine*MB   Thank you!!

Comment: I would think you need `$examineLine * 1MB`.

Comment: '35' + 'mb' would work as a string.

Answer (score 1):

It's actualy "*" symbol instead of "+" and you should provide quantity of MB:

```
$size = 10
$sizeinmb = $size * 1MB
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple...

$size = @("7GB","20GB","40GB")

$size | %{ New-VHD -Path ("D:\HV\VHD\BlankDisk"+$_+".vhdx") -SizeBytes **(($__ *1)/1)** -Dynamic }